# Securing Authorization Header in Ajax Request from Inspect Element

Tags: php, ajax, api, jwt

i need some oppinion on how to securing JWT Token when form submiting using ajax, this is how it looks on google chrome inspect element
[inspect element on chrome browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYqAR.png)
 the token is visible and unknown user can be post some data to its endpoint, any idea to securing the JWT Token? any oppinion accpreciated, thanks!
 using HTTPS resolve this issue?

Comment: Usually you get the jwt token after login, so  only logged user can see it.

Comment: thank you for answering, yes thats the idea of using JWT, but in this case i build the front office website for register member so i think i should secure the API using the token to prevent malicious and unauthentcated user. fyi: the token that i pass to ajax is user for Application as master, any further suggestion?

Comment: But still... is the jwt token generated after login?

Comment: yes, but login functionality is acting in the backend (laravel), and the login credential using let's say "application API", when i return the view it also passing the token, i know this is weird cause the token is being public..

Answer (score 0):

Usual user log in with username/ password (or whatever),  if he login successful then the server will return the jwt token that he can use for the other requests.
So jwt should already be safe (unless unauthenticated users can enter private area, but then you have some other problem to solve).
If you dont want the jwt to be visible in you js code you can store the token in the server session, then make an ajax call to retrieve the token, in pseudocode:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/myscript.php",
  data: {action : "GetToken"},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(token){
     // now you can do whatever you want with the token, if any.
  },
  error: function(){
  }
}
```

The .php

```
<php 
   if isset($_POST["action"] && $_POST["action"] == "GetToken"){
    echo $_SESSION["userToken"];
 }
?>
```

Obviously you have to save the token in the `$_SESSION` when you create it.

Comment: thank you for great explaination, imagine if you have a registration form and its public so anyone can register on your website, what kind of authentication you use to make sure no one else using your register API?

Comment: it depends, api are for all registrated user?

Comment: So just ask for login or automatically login user after registration

Comment: automatically login user after registration